# Cordova + Backbone.js - Delay main.js load until deviceready is fired

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js

I am adapting an existing Backbone.js project to Cordova. Everything works fine except that, on iOS, I can't use `console.log` on the `main.js`. I am using the Cordova console plugin (org.apache.cordova.console) in order to be able to print messages to the console on iOS, and this is working fine in other scripts but not in main.js. I am sure this is due to `deviceready` not being fired yet when main.js is executing.

How can I do to load main.js after deviceready is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main file always is something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    // Start the app
    App.initialize();
}

var App = (function(){

    var App = {};

    App.initialize = function(){
        console.log("App initialize");
        // Your code here...

    };

    return App;

}());
```

I call it app.js

Comment: Oh! Now I feel stupid haha, so obvious I am a javascript total newbie :-P Gràcies